# Manage pip requirments.txt in python container

Tags: python, pip, containers

I have a generic question how people are working with the requirements file in a container environment?
I have number of versions of a application in a container and during the development phases have we migrate from using one module to another, example are we stop using Dropbox to use S3 storage like boto3.

Both Dropbox and Boto3 have there dependencies and installing there extra modules, but how do you clean up an old version of requirement file?
If I only delete Dropbox from Requirements.txt that means the dependencies modules are still there and keeping track of each main components dependencies will kill the administration.

It should be a easy way to findout how what dependancies each module use, but I got stuck in this at the moment and wonder how everyone else are working with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common way to deal with transitive dependencies is using [pip-tools](https://github.com/jazzband/pip-tools):

You keep all your direct dependencies in a `requirements.in` file, e.g.

```
# requirements.in
dropbox
boto3
```

And then generate the `requirements.txt` file with `pip-compile`

```
# pip-compile requirements.in
# cat requirements.txt

#
# This file is autogenerated by pip-compile
# To update, run:
#
#    pip-compile requirements.in
#
boto3==1.17.45
    # via -r requirements.in
botocore==1.20.45
    # via
    #   boto3
    #   s3transfer
certifi==2020.12.5
    # via requests
chardet==4.0.0
    # via requests
dropbox==11.5.0
    # via -r requirements.in
idna==2.10
    # via requests
jmespath==0.10.0
    # via
    #   boto3
    #   botocore
ply==3.11
    # via stone
python-dateutil==2.8.1
    # via botocore
requests==2.25.1
    # via dropbox
s3transfer==0.3.6
    # via boto3
six==1.15.0
    # via
    #   dropbox
    #   python-dateutil
    #   stone
stone==3.2.1
    # via dropbox
urllib3==1.26.4
    # via
    #   botocore
    #   requests
```

`pip-compile` nicely lists, where a transitive dependency comes from.

After changing or removing a top-level dependency, e.g. dropbox, you generate the `requirements.txt` file again.